# Two Identical Divs with jQuery slideToggle, but only one of them is working.

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

would really appreciate some help if possible?

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to respond!

Here is my problem.

I have two identical divs that sit in a row. They contain an h3 and a p.
On click of the h3 I want it to slideToggle the display of the p.

The slideToggle works fine on the first div but on the second div it has no affect at all.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong??

My code is below...

**HTML**

```
<section class="twocol">
<div id="accordionPanel">
<h3 class="accordionControl">This is the title of the content area</h3>
<p class="accordionText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no per erant dicant tritani. Et reque aperiam fabulas nec. Vim ne pericula tincidunt. Id perpetua constituam quo, feugiat pertinax referrentur at per.</p>
</div>
</section>

<section class="twocol">
<div id="accordionPanel">
<h3 class="accordionControl">This is the title of the content area</h3>
<p class="accordionText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no per erant dicant tritani. Et reque aperiam fabulas nec. Vim ne pericula tincidunt. Id perpetua constituam quo, feugiat pertinax referrentur at per.</p>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#accordionPanel {
@include lightgreygradient;}

.accordionControl {   
&:hover {cursor: pointer;}
}

.accordionText {display:none;}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#accordionPanel').on('click', '.accordionControl', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).next('.accordionText').not(':animated').slideToggle();  
});
```

Comment: too identical I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two divs with the same id `<div id="accordionPanel">`, use a class instead : `<div class="accordionPanel">`, then your javascript will reference the element using the class instead :

```
$('.accordionPanel').on('click', '.accordionControl', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.accordionText').not(':animated').slideToggle();  
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much! I love this community.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `$('#accordionPanel')` to `$(document)` in your code

```js
$(document).on('click', '.accordionControl', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).next('.accordionText').not(':animated').slideToggle();  
});
```

```html
<section class="twocol">
<div id="accordionPanel">
<h3 class="accordionControl">This is the title of the content area</h3>
<p class="accordionText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no per erant dicant tritani. Et reque aperiam fabulas nec. Vim ne pericula tincidunt. Id perpetua constituam quo, feugiat pertinax referrentur at per.</p>
</div>
</section>

<section class="twocol">
<div id="accordionPanel">
<h3 class="accordionControl">This is the title of the content area</h3>
<p class="accordionText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no per erant dicant tritani. Et reque aperiam fabulas nec. Vim ne pericula tincidunt. Id perpetua constituam quo, feugiat pertinax referrentur at per.</p>
</div>
</section>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! changing the id to a class did the trick. Appreciate you taking the time to respond cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have more than 1 HTML elements with same value of `id` i.e. 'accordionPanel'. You should always have a unique id for all HTML elements. So, you might want to use classnames here to bind the action.

```
$('.twocol').on('click', '.accordionControl', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('.twocol').find('.accordionText').not(':animated').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Cheers. Thank you for taking the time to respond! Helped a lot.